# Unable to upgrade the jboss-eap from 7.0 to 7.2 in Redhat linux server

Tags: jboss, upgrade, redhat

> `/jboss-cli.sh
>   You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
>   [disconnected /] connect
>   [standalone@localhost:9990 /] patch apply /opt/jboss-eap-7.2 --preserve=[bin/init.d/jboss-eap-rhel.sh,bin/standalone.conf]
>   /opt/jboss-eap-7.2 is a directory.`

Unable to upgrade the jboss-eap from 7.0 to 7.2 in Redhat linux server

This is for a Redhat Linux server, we already have the jboss-eap 7.0 available. However, now we need to upgrade with jboss-eap 7.2.

It should get upgraded to jboss-eap 7.2

Answer (score 0):

as described on the [Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/patching_and_upgrading_guide/index) the issue is that you're not selecting the patch.

How to apply a patch (which is a file, in this a zip file):

```
patch apply /path/to/downloaded-patch.zip
```

What are you doing:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] patch apply /opt/jboss-eap-7.2 --preserve=[bin/init.d/jboss-eap-rhel.sh,bin/standalone.conf]
```

You're sending, therefore, a directory `/opt/jboss-eap-7.2` instead of the file.